# HTML element passing first value in PHP array

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've got a php page that gets data from mysql database as $certs[] and populates that as a table:
($db is read from file, it is constant)

```html
 <?php echo $cert["id"] ?> 
 <button type="button" class="awe" title="Edit" id="editbtn" onclick="openNewModalWithValue('Modal2')" value =<?php echo $cert["id"] ?> >&#xf019</button>
 <form action="sample.php" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value=<?php echo $cert["id"] ?>>      
  <input type="hidden" name="db" value=<?php echo $db ?>>
  <button type="submit" name="mission" title="Delete">&#xf00d</button>
 </form>
```

And I try to get `id` value in Modal window. (Like press 'EDIT' button and you get modal window with values set.) So my Modal window is:

```html
<form id="modal-form" method="POST" action="sample2.php">        
 <input type="number" id="idb" name="idbase" />
 <input type="text" id="nme" name="name"/>     
 <input type="hidden" name="db" value=<?php echo $db; ?>>
 <input type="hidden" id= "idbs" name="idbs" />     
 <button id="form-submit" type="submit" >Edit</button>
</form>
```

and the Javascript for opening modal window is:

```js
function openNewModalWithValue(modal){
 document.getElementById(modal).style.display = "block";
 document.getElementById("idb").value = document.getElementById("editbtn").value;   
}
```

The problem is that even though PHP sends $certs[] values correctly, and table populates correctly, when I hit 'edit' button, I get preserved values of item#1 in PHP array, no matter which row/data I click. 
Is there an easier way rather than applying counter to every row and operating with it?

Comment: What is `$db` ?

Comment: @user2486 "($db is read from file, it is constant)" and does not really correspond to my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem may be idb is multiple id in DOM. document.getElementById find Dom in whole page. so you must provide unique id